# Unable to overload android.content.Context using JPype

Tags: python, jpype

I am trying to implement android context but it says no overload found while creating object.

My Code:

```
 mContext = jpype.JClass("android.content.Context")
handle =TestClient(mContext)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: No matching overloads found for constructor testClient(_jpype._JClass), options are:
E               public TestClient(android.content.Context)
```

I tried with JObject as well

```
 mContext = jpype.JObject("android.content.Context")
handle =TestClient(mContext)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: No matching overloads found for constructor testClient(java.lang.String), options are:
E               public TestClient(android.content.Context)
```

How to pass this as `android.content.Context`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by exposing Android jar and adding it to classpath.
Post that you have use same `jpype.jpackage("android.content.Context")`.

This return object in _jpype.JClass.

Note: This is a hack and not very good solution to use.